# Print Job using xm_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ghostscript

I am just wondering anyone tried executing a print job using SQL Server xp_cmdshell ?

I am using GhostScript to print some pdf files dynamically depends on condition and I managed to call gsprint but not able to print the job.

Got Couldn't open Windows GDI driver error.

If I copy and paste the statement and execute it using Command Prompt, it works.

Just wonder what is missing ...

Thanks ...

Comment: using a commsnd prompt on the actual SQL Server? Note that xp_cmdshell runs under a different widows account and that's probably your issue.

Comment: Any idea how to check what account it is using ?

Comment: First google search came up with this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lcris/2009/10/27/finding-information-about-which-account-xp_cmdshell-is-running-as/. This site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx says _The Windows process spawned by xp_cmdshell has the same security rights as the SQL Server service account._. So go into your services applet and check (by default it's local\system). You could try changing the service account to _your_ account or you could try using a proxy account to troubleshoot

Comment: I login the Database Engine using Windows Authentication - Service Account and tested the xp_cmdshell using Query. Before I do the testing, I setup all the required printer for this Service Account already. The output statement returned by GhostScript showing the Printer server I selected is available. That's why I think tricky ...

Comment: I did not manage to get it run successfully using Query but when I schedule it as a job and RunAs Service Account, the entire thing works.

Comment: Run this: `SELECT servicename, status_desc, service_account FROM sys.dm_server_services WHERE servicename NOT LIKE '%text%'`. **SQL Server Agent** is the windows account your **job** runs as. **SQL Server** is what `xp_cmdshell` runs as. A simple fix is to open `services.msc` from start/run and set your SQL Service account to be the same as your Agent service account (cause you know that one works). Longer term, selecting service accounts takes a bit more thought.

Comment: I fixed it by running sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account. It fixed the issue : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190359(v=sql.105).aspx ... thanks for your tips and I will check out your script too.

Comment: Yes along the lines of my second comment. Glad you sorted it

Comment: Thanks Nick. My approach is not a perfect solution but I found that I have better control over the logic flow using store procedure and command line printing rather than coding it on SSRS.

Comment: Since SSRS is a reporting tool not a control tool, it would seem this is a good idea.